# If statement to compare two dates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

Im trying to update a plist file automaticlly if the file is over 24 hours old, but i cant figure out how to compare the two dates.

```
// get last modification date
NSString *dir = path;
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:dir error:nil];
NSDate *date = [attributes fileModificationDate];

NSDate *fileModPlus24Hours = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(24*60*60) sinceDate:date];
```

Thinking about something like:

```
if (date > fileModPlus24Hours) {
    // update file
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([date compare:fileModPlus24Hours] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // update file
}
```

The result of compare can be `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame`.

And I don't think your code will work either by comparing `date` to `fileModPlus24Hours`. You should be comparing the current date to `fileModPlus24Hours` instead:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
if ([now compare:fileModPlus24Hours] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // update file
}
```

Comment: Yeah i think you are right. Tt seem to be working with you solution. I will check in 24 hours ;-) Thank you

Comment: Actually you can check now, modify **(24*60*60)** by **60** only (one minute) just for testing, then put it back to **(24*60*60)** :)